# Thymleaf is not reading the model data returned from controller

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

[Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8scPB.png)

I'm new to Thymeleaf. It's a simple HelloWorld app in which I want to display the **model** message returned from controller. It's running successfully but it's not displaying the message returned from controller.
But when the same code is running with a given **jsp** file it's reading which is a common thing.

`WelcomeController` class is

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    private String pass="Welcome To ThymLeaf";

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String welcomeUser(Map<String,String> model) {
        model.put("message", pass);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My `index.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>ThymLeaf Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/main.css}" href="../../main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Spring Boot Using ThymLeaf</h1>
        <h2>
            <span th:if="${message != null}"
                th:text="'Message:' + ${message}">> 
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's displaying  **Spring Boot Using ThymLeaf** but not the message attribute because it is coming with a null value but why?

Comment: but it's EL how can i miss $ and the problem is it's coming with a **null** that's why it's not showing the **Message:**

Comment: I dont know what gets passed to your function when you specify the Parameter as Map<String,String> model, but you usually use Model, ModelMap or ModelAndView. With those this code should work. Is there any reason why you use Map<String,String>?

Comment: @espendennis that's also valid Spring code and doesn't make a difference in html-tempates (Thymleaf, jsp, EL, ect.).

Comment: yes and the problem lies on **${ message }** it's not reading the data within the model attribute is it the way we access model data in thymleaf

Comment: View the source in your browser and make sure it's actually interpreting the file it as Thymeleaf.

Comment: Solved your problem ? @Stone

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer

```
<span th:if="${message} != null">
  <span th:text= "'Message:' + ${message}"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not- null check is not correct here , do something like this :--

```
<span th:if="${message} != null or ${message} !=  '' ">
  <span th:text= "${message}"></span>
</span>
```

**PS**:- make sure you're putting commas correctly otherwise your page will end up with error.

Comment: no the problem is **${message}** it's not getting access to the model attribute